# Stop windows from showing up as 'tasks' from task manager WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program that opens multiple windows. I have used [this method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44b613e4-4b45-4e54-a43d-96ebbeb28185/) to hide them from ALT+TAB. Now I need the new windows to stop showing up in the 'tasks' tab of task manager.

I don't need the process not to show up in task manager, I just don't want all the windows my program opens to show up in the 'task' tab.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to get rid of: http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g324/thezaza101/Tasklist.jpg

-Thanks

Comment: how are you opening the new Windows from the main one? Are you running multiple processes or only one?

Comment: Is one of your windows the main window?

Comment: How about `FormX.ShowInTaskBar = false'

Comment: What do these hidden windows do?

Comment: Main window opens the windows i need to hide in task manager, @ BalamBalam They just run passively, its like a 'post it' program,

Comment: @David Heffernan I have used the .Hide() method on the main window. @ Henk Holterman it still shows in task manager

Comment: You need to make the other windows owned by the main window in Win32 terms. No idea how to do that in WPF mind you!

Comment: @David Heffernan thanks that helped a lot, I'll answer my question for everyone to see!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved thanks to David Heffernan.

On my main window i added a static window field which references my main window.

```
public static Window main;
Public MainWindow()
{
main = this;
}
```

On the windows I need to hide from task manager and ALT+TAB, I made my main window its owner:

```
public HiddenWindow()
{
this.Owner = MainWindow.main;
}
```

Its really simple, it hides the window from the 'tasks' tab on task manager and also stop people from ALT+TABing into your program.

Comment: This solution work perfectly. instead of type of 'window' , I use 'From'. It work like a charm!!

Answer (score 4):

For WPF the only way I currently know of is to set your window's title to `string.Empty` or set `WindowStyle` to `ToolWindow`. Setting `ShowInTaskBar` to false does not hide your window from the applications list.

Comment: That's a Winforms answer to a WPF question.

Comment: My bad, extremely tired and assumed. Thanks for pointing that out; I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use WindowInteropHelper.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SourceInitialized += (s, e) =>
        {
            var win = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            win.Owner = GetDesktopWindow();
        };
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hvae the same problem(may some different), here is my code:

```
subWindow.hide();//this will hide the subWindow
subWindow.show();//if want to show again
```

you will not see window in task or AlT+TAB after use hide()